# How to replace TouchPoint on mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch, mouseclick-event

Please to say me, how can I replace command TouchPoint similarly on mouse click? I add my code which I must change:

```
 private Dictionary<int, UIElement> myEllipses =
        new Dictionary<int, UIElement>();
 private void cnv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Width = 30;
        ellipse.Height = 30;
        ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Gold;


        TouchPoint tp = e.GetPosition(cnv);
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, tp.Bounds.Top);
        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, tp.Bounds.Left);

        myEllipses[e.TouchDevice.Id] = ellipse;


        cnv.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `GetPosition()` method to get the point where mouse was clicked. Try this :

```
private void cnv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point clickedPt = e.GetPosition(this);
    var xPos = clickedPt.X;
    var yPos = clickedPt.Y;
}
```